# What do I do if I believe there is serial down voting going on?

Tags: support, abuse

I think someone is going around and purposely down-voting my questions and answers. When I logged on today it said I had lost over 24 reputation to down-voting. It's not just on one question which would make a little sense. It's questions that have been inactive for 6 months or so. How can I report this?

-2   29 mins ago    downvote    Blocks won't break without right tool

-2   33 mins ago    downvote    How can I make chests in a desert biome when there are no trees in Minecraft?

-2   36 mins ago    downvote    What is this Item I found in Minecraft?

-2   36 mins ago    downvote    How do you stop squid from despawning?

-2   2 hours ago    downvote    Is it possible to fire a lock-on Rocket Launcher in “Dumbfire” mode?

+2   8 hours ago    accept  What are the actual names of the stages in Centipede?

-2   6 hours ago    downvote    Is it possible to fire a lock-on Rocket Launcher in “Dumbfire” mode?

-2   6 hours ago    downvote    What Items do creepers destroy?

-2   6 hours ago    downvote    Do armed zombies deal normal damage or sword damage?

-2   6 hours ago    downvote    Mob vs. Mob in Minecraft

-2   10 hours ago   downvote    Minecraft Hunger Games late-game strategy

-2   10 hours ago   downvote    No experience from mining iron?

-2   10 hours ago   downvote    What is this Item I found in Minecraft?

-2   11 hours ago   downvote    Are scores stacked when playing with 2 people in Centipede?

-2   11 hours ago   downvote    What are the actual names of the stages in Centipede?

-4   6 hours ago    2 events     Zombie Kids in Minecraft?

-4   8 hours ago    2 events     Blocks won't break without right tool

Minus 34 reputation today. If someone thinks this isn't a serial down vote I would RECONSIDER THINGS.

It appears someone was down-voting me.

+16  17 hours ago   reversal    Serial downvoting reversed

+8   6 hours ago    reversal    Serial downvoting reversed

Comment: Point of fact, that's only 16 rep lost.  Unless you deleted a post or four, in which case, you've got that rep back.

Comment: @fbueckert No it's 26.

Comment: Serial downvoting only applies to downvoting in a small period of time.  Prior to this meta post, you only had eight downvotes.  NOW it's 26, due to people paying more attention to your posts, but them's the breaks when you post on Meta.

Comment: Most of these are either on the first page of the minecraft tag page, or were on the front page in the last day or so, so it's fairly reasonable that this would happen organically.

Comment: There is a system in place to revert serial downvoting.  In the meantime, humor the thought that there may actually be something wrong with these posts and see if you can improve them.

Comment: I would not reconsider it.  If it *is* serial downvoting, and I'm not saying it is, that was, at most a tiny period of time prior to you posting this.  Everything after that comes straight from the increased attention your posts have gotten since.  As @OrigamiRobot says, perhaps you should consider that the community sees a problem with your posts, and that they require improvement.

Comment: Well the -4 from the question Lock-on launcher in dumbfire mode is because your awnser is wrong so you can atleast not count those along. That just leaves all your centipede and minecraft question/awnsers.

Comment: "*It appears someone was down-voting me.*" well, there was no question there were downvotes, the question was if they were of the serial variety. Although I find the entry you didn't mention interesting "+16 / -35  7 hours ago  2 events   Serial upvoting reversed"

Comment: @OrigamiRobot (fbueckert too) I don't think we need to personalize the event of getting downvoted from the "community" when it's probably just 1-2 people doing it. What do you think? All these while the people upvoted his posts and all of a sudden the community turned against not one but several of _his_ questions? Even if someone _were_ to consider that scenario it doesn't mean that what Young is saying is not valid. The possibility still exists that there was a serial downvoter. If we pick up _any_ random question and start scrutinizing it we will can always find some flaw or the other.

Comment: @fbueckert (OrigamiRobot too) And I have seen the community behavior on this particular site. We have questions that are completely unresearched and yet upvoted as well questions that sound legit but still randomly downvoted. Posts such as these: (http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system ) stand as testimony to this fact. I strongly feel it is morally wrong to try and convince a person that he was the cause of some incident when he was actually just a victim.

Comment: @Mugen Review [this meta post, please](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/what-is-a-reasonable-approach-to-deal-with-other-arqade-users-that-seem-to-be-ra).  He's only a victim in the sense that his choices have found to be lacking in this community.  We have standards here that had not been met, and portraying it as victimizing a user is strawmanning to the extreme.

Comment: @fbueckert Okay I just now noticed the last 2 lines in the OP's post. It seems that the serial downvoting got detected and it got reversed automatically. I apologize I didn't see that earlier. IMO that beats the whole point of continuing this discussion anymore. Also, I did see the link you provided. I have nothing more to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally downvoting sprees happen on enough questions that they are automatically detected and reverted. This case is kinda borderline; we moderators don't have enough data about who downvoted what when.

You'll have to [contact the Stack Exchange team.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/contact) The link is in the footer.

Comment: Automatic detection is a daily process, of note, so it may be simpler to wait and see what happens. We log data whether we manually handle these or they're automatically detected.

Comment: @GraceNote This number of events seems right on the line of somebody who knows there's a reversal script and is trying to stay under the radar. Or maybe it's multiple users. Either way I don't feel like I have enough data to act.

Answer (score 2):

Worry less about your reputation and worry more about the quality of your answers. People who worry about their reputation this much tend to deserve the reputation penalties that they accumulate.

That said, it looks like someone was serial downvoting you, at least some of it. But again, you shouldn't worry about these things. Real serial downvoting gets reversed by the system.

Unfortunately, being obsessed with rep is not something the system can undo for you, so that's something you'll have to fix yourself. What you should worry about is not the points you're losing; you should actually be worried about the message that downvotes are designed to give you: that fellow users consider your posts worth downvoting.

Comment: @SevenSideDie To be honest I couldn't care about the reputation. I was mainly bummed because someone had a problem with me.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Welcome to the Internet. You may want to take a break from the site if it's affecting you emotionally that much.

Comment: As for not caring about rep, I'm not convinced. Posting things like [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7478/how-much-rep-can-you-earn-in-a-day) and [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7499/why-is-my-answer-in-the-negatives-when-i-did-research-and-provided-a-video-copy) to meta give the impression of being fairly preoccupied by rep. We all like rep, but focusing too much on the numbers will distract you from the point of rep, which is a measure of how much trust the community has in your answers.

Comment: @SevenSideDie the first one was out of curiosity. The second question was because I wasn't understanding why it was negative.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I'm afraid I'm with SevenSidedDie on this one (how did THAT happen!? :P).  Your own actions have shown that you answer bountied questions, and delete them when you're proven wrong.  If that's not focussing on rep, then I don't know how to classify that.  You're making good inroads in improvement right now, though, so let's try to keep that going, shall we?